PySpark is not creating Dataframe inside the function, when parameters are passed when calling the function
I want to create the dataframe using functions.
I have a list of Countries as Row objects.
like below:
country_list=df_correct_countries.select('NewCountry').dropDuplicates().collect()
for i in country_list:
    print(i)

###OUTPUT 

Row(NewCountry='Senegal')
Row(NewCountry='Algeria')
Row(NewCountry='Nigeria')
Row(NewCountry='Morocco')
Row(NewCountry='Ethiopia')

I am passing this to a create_df function using a for loop, as  which takes 2 arguments, (original_df,country):
Below is my create_df function.
def create_df(df,cnt):
         #["NewCountry"]
    cnt=str(cnt)
    # print(cn)
    # print(tf)
    cnt=df.where(col("NewCountry")==str(cnt))
    return cnt

This is how I call my function:

for j in country_list:
    create_df(df_correct_countries,j['NewCountry'])  ##NewCountry is column name of my coorect country column, which I have collected in list

Inside function, each time the function is called, value of cnt is a country.
I want to create new dataframe ,where I want to filter out rows,which only belongs to current calue of cnt.
But, its not creating the df.
Function runs whithout error, but when I try to display a country, it throws error.
display(EquatorialGuinea)

###Error
NameError: name 'EquatorialGuinea' is not defined


But, when I create dataframe outside the function, with same country, it works.
like this:
df_correct_countries.where(col("NewCountry")=='EquatorialGuinea')

Above works.
Can anyone tell me what's the issue?
Above all things I have tried.

Any updates on trying to see if the memory is an issue?

for j in country_list:
create_df(df_correct_countries,j['NewCountry'])  ##NewCountry is column name of my coorect country column, which I have collected in list

I think the problem might be you aren't using any data struct to hold the new dataframes that are created by the create_df function inside of this loop. Since the function returns the filtered df, you would need to store those dfs somewhere (like in a dictionary) or print them from within the loop in order for it to display correctly. For example,
    country_dfs = {}

for j in country_list:
    country_name = j['NewCountry']
    country_dfs[country_name] = create_df(df_correct_countries, country_name)

display(country_dfs['EquatorialGuinea'])


I am reading a file, of size around 1 gb. If I store all df in a single datas tructure,  will it cause memory issue?

It should be fine but try it and see what happens
